# How to set data from database to combo box?

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, classcastexception

In this code, I take 1 `JComboBox` and get data from the database, and put it into combo box. but it gives an exception, I.E. `ClassCastException`.

```
package com.admin;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.entity.DepartmentTable;
import com.helper.FactoryProvider;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Demo {

    private JFrame frame;
    private static JComboBox comboBox;
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Demo window = new Demo();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    factory = FactoryProvider.getFactory();
                    setCombobox();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private void setCombobox() {
                Session session = factory.openSession();
                Query q = session.createQuery("select dept_name from 
                DepartmentTable");

                List<DepartmentTable> list = q.list();
                for (DepartmentTable dept : list) {
                    comboBox.addItem(dept.getDept_name());
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public Demo() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 816, 408);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setBounds(342, 55, 183, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.entity.DepartmentTable (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.entity.DepartmentTable is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.admin.Demo$1.setCombobox(Demo.java:41)
    at com.admin.Demo$1.run(Demo.java:30)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the little bit of code you provided, but the line *txt_department.addItem(dept.getDept_name());* probably should be *txt_department.addItem(dept);*

Comment: txt_department.addItem(dept); it also gives same error. can i share my whole code.

Comment: The idea would be to create a [mre] and update your question with just the code that's required to solve the problem.  Your goal should be to write a tiny bit of code and test it.  Once your tiny bit of code works, write another tiny bit of code.  Writing hundreds of lines of code before running your first test dooms you to failure.

Comment: Now I have changed my code into a small piece. please help me to solve this exception.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is rise automatically by JVM whenever we try to improperly typecast a class from one type to another i.e when we’re trying to typecast parent object to child type or when we try to typecast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.

```
package com.admin;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.entity.DepartmentTable;
import com.helper.FactoryProvider;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Demo {

    private JFrame frame;
    private static JComboBox comboBox;
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Demo window = new Demo();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    factory = FactoryProvider.getFactory();
                    setCombobox();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private void setCombobox() {
                Session session = factory.openSession();
                Query q = session.createQuery("from DepartmentTable");

                List<DepartmentTable> list = q.list();
                for (DepartmentTable dept : list) {     
                    String str=(String)dept.getDept_name();
                    
                    Object obj=(Object)str;

                    comboBox.addItem(obj);
                }

            }
        });
    }

public Demo() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 816, 408);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setBounds(342, 55, 183, 35);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
}
```

}

Details explanasion of [ClassCastException](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-solve-class-cast-exceptions-in-java/)